# Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string

I am getting this error in one project and the code works perfectly fine on another project. I have tried multiple to duplicate the code as it is. Is there a way to find where the error originated from??

```
@if (ViewBag.RolesForThisUser != null)
{
    <div style="background-color:lawngreen;">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Roles For This User")
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  @foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser) //this line
                    {
                        <li>@s</li>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspected `ViewBag.RolesForThisUser` itself already contains a `string`, neither an array nor collection of strings (e.g. `string[]` or `List<string>`), hence using `foreach` loop is pointless (and `string` itself contains `char[]` array which explains why type conversion failed). You can simply display it without `foreach`:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.RolesForThisUser))
{
    <div style="background-color:lawngreen;">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Roles For This User")
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @ViewBag.RolesForThisUser
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Or assign a string collection to `ViewBag.RolesForThisUser` from `GET` method so that you can use `foreach` loop, like example below:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    list.Add("Administrator");
    // add other values here

    ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = list;

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@if (ViewBag.RolesForThisUser != null)
{
    <div style="background-color:lawngreen;">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Roles For This User")
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser)
                    {
                        <p>@s</p>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```